# Printing a report in lightning

Tags: reporting, lightning-apps, custom-report-type, printable

Is it possible to print a report in lightning without the rest of the browser items?  My issue is that none of the aggregations save.  Perhaps there is a chrome extension that may solve the issue.

Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that Lightning is in a constant state of flux. It's full of active content. There are many layers of Javascript that can be changing your content at any moment in time. The issue for a printer driver is "how to freeze" that content at any given moment in time long enough to print it. If your browser will allow you to break down the content, you may be able to print it. Otherwise, your best option will be to take a screen capture and then print that. I strongly suspect this will be an ongoing issue with lightning pages.

Comment: Another issue is that the report is in a frame, so any printing only prints what's on screen.  It's basically impossible to print outside excel

Comment: Also, talked to our SF rep and he pointed out that it's a documented limitation of Lightning at than point.  Although the printing of the classic reports is less than stellar